# How to plot paired data in a scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a data frame that has paired samples from different time points ("time 0" and "time 3") for the same subjects. How can I generate a scatter plot with the x-coordinate corresponding to "time 0" and the y-coordinate corresponding to "time 3" for each subject.

```
subject = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
time = c(0,3,0,3,0,3)
dependent_variable = c(1,5,4,12,3,9)
df = data.frame(subject, time, dependent_variable)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could reshape your data using e.g. `tidy::pivot_wider`:

```r
subject = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
time = c(0,3,0,3,0,3)
dependent_variable = c(1,5,4,12,3,9)
df = data.frame(subject, time, dependent_variable)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_wide <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = dependent_variable, names_prefix = "time")

ggplot(df_wide, aes(time0, time3, color = factor(subject))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted +1, it is always great to see a post teaching other the importance of rehsping data when using `ggplot2`!